# Self Signed Certificate Error installing Terraform in Azure DevOps Services pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

in Azure DevOps Services pipeline, I'm trying to install Terraform using the following task.

[image]

[image]

and I'm getting the following error message. I am not sure if I need to import a cert to a cert store?

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you download this file directly in the browser? https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.29/terraform_0.12.29_windows_amd64.zip
Please check whether you have set up a firewall or network monitoring. In addition, this version of Terraform is out of date. The latest version
is 0.13.5.

Comment: yeah, Im able to download this manually through the browser

Comment: Which agent you are using? I could download the 0.12.29 with hosted agent windows-2019. You could try to run the pipeline with hosted agent windows-2019 and you could also try to use the task **Terraform tool installer** instead of **Terraform installer** to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer that seemed to work [for someone who had this problem](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12010#issuecomment-626867838) and found the answer in the [Azure Pipelines docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/proxy?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#specify-proxy-bypass-urls), which I'm quoting below:

### Specify proxy bypass URLs

> Create a .proxybypass file in the agent's root directory that specifies regular expressions (in ECMAScript syntax) to match URLs that should bypass the proxy. For example:

```
github\.com
hashicorp\.com
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this but did not work unfortunately..